# How to see inside a sealed document without opening it?

Tags: travel, work, security

A company is paying me to transport highly important legal documents to the US. I'm a bit skeptical as I never heard of the company and got connected through a friend. I don't want to be transporting drugs or anything illegal. I asked if I can see inside the document before it's sealed and they said no but I can hold a flash light up to it to see it's all paper.

I'd feel safer if I test using a method I thought up. Any other ideas? If I had the resources I'd put it through an x-ray machine or have a dog sniff it from drugs.

Comment: Remember the saying.... if it sounds too good to be true it probably is... Ask yourself why they are hiring you to transport these rather than using a traditional global shipping company? Unless they don't want the paper trail those companies create...

Comment: Breaking a seal would be considered illegal most places, and we shouldn't aid in illegal activities.

Comment: @ErinGoBragh yes, why should they pay you more than a global courier? When they are offering next day delivery and the like ? But even if it's not something fishy inside, it's a part of your duty to not be interested in the contents.

Comment: Don't forget, airport security will surely ask if you're carrying anything that was given to you by another person.  Answer yes, and you'll miss your flight (maybe all flights, ever).  Answer no, and you've broken a law right there (in the USA, that would be a felony), as well as possibly endangering everyone on the flight with you.  Hopefully, you're not already in this to the point you can't walk away -- you might consider asking the police for protective custody until you're able to reach the USA.  Meanwhile, this is likely to be closed as off topic.

Answer (score 2):

Give it to the police and explain the situation. Walk away.

If they were concerned about security they would pay a transport company to securely transport it. Not you.